# Ajax autocomplete php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, autocomplete

сталкнулся с такой трудностью, не могу найти способ сделать 2 поля инпуп которые будут связаны друг с другом базой mysql, использую плагин autocomplete

сделал скрипт который достаёт данные из базы :

```
    $test = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from user where first like '%". $_POST['first'] ."%' and last like '%". $_POST['last']. "%'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($test)){
            $_SESSION['first_ses'] = $row['first'];
            $_SESSION['last_ses'] = $row['last'];
        }
```

Но дальше информации не нащёл
Если это тупой вопрос особо ногами не бейте, недавно начал учить php и js

[image: Вот и сама база:]

как сделать так что-бы при вводе имени в одно поле предлагали подходящие фамилии и наоборот?

Comment: учите дальше js и через месяцок получится

Comment: Сделай на бэке обработчик через https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php (ищет похожие слова), и подключай ajax запрос к нему